# Import table into Word Document with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ms-word, visual-studio-2022, office-addins

I am building a Word add-in. When the search query is matched, a table is created with the results. My import button copies the table data and pastes into the word document. The issue I am having is that no matter what I change, I cannot get the code to overwrite the default table margins in the Word document. Any advice would be appreciated. I have not dealt with JavaScript since about 2014.

Import:

```
if (importButton) {
    importButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (queuedTables.length > 0) {
            const tempTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");
            tempTextArea.style.position = "absolute";
            tempTextArea.style.left = "-9999px";
            tempTextArea.value = queuedTables[0];
            document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);
            tempTextArea.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);

            const customTableStyle = 'style="width: 100%;"';

            const modifiedTableHTML = queuedTables[0];

            Word.run(function (context) {
                const documentBody = context.document.body;
                const range = documentBody.getRange("End");
                range.insertHtml(modifiedTableHTML, "End");
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    queuedTables = [];
                });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[Imported Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOePu.png)

I have tried a lot of different things. Not really sure how to proceed here.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't appear to be possible as the Javascript API does not support it